# C# and Oracle, login Form: Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object

Tags: c#, oracle, object, state

```
  private void bLogIn(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string logging = "select * from CLIENT where LOGIN='" + this.t_Login.Text + "' and PASSWORD='" + this.t_Password.Text + "' ;";

        OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection("Data Source=XXX/orcl;User Id=XXX;Password=XXX;");
        OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();

        cmd.CommandText = logging;
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }



        int count = 0;

        OracleDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();  // At this line there is the error: Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object

        while (reader.Read())
        {
           count = count + 1;
        }
        if (count == 1)
        {
        MessageBox.Show("Welcome");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Wrong Password");
        }
        conn.Dispose();
    }
```

This is code that was working for MySQL, but after conversion to Oracle it's not working. What am I doing wrong? Where's the difference. It should be so easy as in MySQL, right?

Why "OracleDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();" causes error: "Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object" ???

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are not assingning the connection to cmd.. try code below

```
OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
cmd.connection = conn;
cmd.CommandText = logging;
int count = 0;
OracleDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

Comment: Well I was rewriting this code from my Polish version of it ;D And I just somewhere lost it, but in my original piece of code it is there, so that wasn't cause the error.

http://pasteboard.co/x9cxGjX.png

Comment: There were 2 errors. 1 was that I had a ";" sign at the end of Oracle query, and then, after simplifying my code to paste it here (cleaning from polish comments), afeter run app again I rewrote the second error, which I get by earsing by mistake "cmd.connection = conn;". So that was it ; )

Comment: @evilferber - There is a site - error translator which you can use in the future: [finderr.net](http://finderr.net/search). 

In this case it shows description like in [example](http://finderr.net/search?q=Ze%20wzgl%C4%99du%20na%20bie%C5%BC%C4%85cy%20stan%20obiektu):  "Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object."